# Animation in callback function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a hover animation for divs and want them to be back to their original position 
when user hovers out. I have

```
$('.Img').live({
            mouseover: function(){

            $(this).css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
            var tooltip=$(this).next().attr('id');


          var tooltipDiv=$('#tooltip-' + tooltip);

          tooltipDiv.css('display', 'block');
          tooltipDiv.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);

          tooltipDiv.animate({'opacity':'1','top':'-=10'},500);

        },
        mouseout: function (){            
          $instance = $(this).css({'cursor': 'auto'});

          //back to the original position....but not sure how to do it....
           tooltipDiv.animate.....

        }
        })
```

I have to use live because I am using Jquery 1.6. Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them to "animate" back to their original position as you did in the initial step?  Or do you want them to just instantly go back to where they were to start with?

Either way its just a mater of working in reverse.  Your animations are pretty minimal and you know where the starting points were to begin with (`opacity: 0`,`top: [$#]+=10`).  The big thing you will run into is inconsistencies with the abrupt animation stops.  If you tell jQuery to move the item `top+=10` on the `mouseout` event it could end up in a different place then what you were expecting based on how the animation queue is currently set (this happens a lot with rapid mousein/mouseout).  Or it may continue to run the animation in its entirety which would also look weird.

Read up on using `.stop()` to get the animations to behave properly: [jQuery .stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

The trick is to have it go back to its initial starting position instead of an unexpected one.  It could be as easy as hard coding the pixel value into the code.  Or I would set a variable to read the initial positions on load like so:

```
$('.Img').live({
    mouseover: function(){
      selector = $(this).next();
      sel_top = selector.css('top');
      sel_opa = selector.css('opacity');

      selector.animate({'opacity':'1','top':'-=10'},500);

    },
    mouseout: function (){            
      selector.animate({'opacity' : sel_opa, 'top' : sel_top},500);
    }
})
```